# Using mutex to synchronize two kernel threads causes a system panic

Tags: linux, kernel, mutex, panic

I used the mutex to synchronize the two kernel threads. After running, panic occurred in the system and abnormal memory was found in mutex by kdump.

Here is a simplified code example, You can run it directly to reproduce the problem.
I changed the memory allocation method to use kmalloc instead of vmalloc, and then it worked, Who knows why？

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct product {
    struct list_head list;
    struct mutex lock;
    bool finish;
};

struct task_struct *task1;
struct task_struct *task2;

spinlock_t spin;
struct list_head products;

struct product *create_product(void)
{
    struct product *p_prod;

    p_prod = vmalloc(sizeof(struct product));
//    p_prod = kmalloc(sizeof(struct product), GFP_KERNEL);
    if(!p_prod)
        return NULL;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&p_prod->list);
    mutex_init(&p_prod->lock);
    p_prod->finish = false;

    return p_prod;
}

void remove_product(struct product **pp_prod)
{
    vfree(*pp_prod);
//    kfree(*pp_prod);
    *pp_prod = NULL;
}

int producer(void *data)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        struct product *p_prod = create_product();
        if(!p_prod)
            continue;

        spin_lock(&spin);
        list_add_tail(&p_prod->list, &products);
        spin_unlock(&spin);

        while (true)
        {
            mutex_lock(&p_prod->lock);
            if(p_prod->finish)
            {
                mutex_unlock(&p_prod->lock);
                schedule();
                break;
            }
            mutex_unlock(&p_prod->lock);
        }
        remove_product(&p_prod);
    }

    do_exit(0);
}

int consumer(void *data)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        struct product *p_prod;

        spin_lock(&spin);
        if(list_empty(&products))
        {
            spin_unlock(&spin);
            schedule();
            continue;
        }
        p_prod = list_first_entry(&products, struct product, list);
        list_del(&p_prod->list);
        spin_unlock(&spin);

        mutex_lock(&p_prod->lock);
        p_prod->finish = true;
        mutex_unlock(&p_prod->lock);
    }

    do_exit(0);
}

static int __init kdemo_init(void) {
    printk(">>> demo driver begin!\n");

    spin_lock_init(&spin);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&products);

    task1 = kthread_run(producer, NULL, "hdz-producer");
    task2 = kthread_run(consumer, NULL, "hdz-consumer");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit kdemo_exit(void) {
    kthread_stop(task1);
    kthread_stop(task2);

    printk(">>> demo driver exit!\n");
}

module_init(kdemo_init);
module_exit(kdemo_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("xxxx@xxx.com");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

dmesg log and consumer stack

```
[  176.599116] >>> demo driver begin!
[  177.167659] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000fb0
[  177.167695] IP: [<ffffffff9e0caa47>] wake_q_add+0x17/0x50
[  177.167719] PGD 0
[  177.167729] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
[  177.167743] Modules linked in: kdemo(OE) mpt3sas mptctl mptbase nvmet_rdma nvmet nvme_rdma nvme_fabrics nvme nvme_core drbd(OE) dell_rbu kvdo(OE) uds(OE) bonding sha512_ssse3 sha512_generic qat_api(OE) usdm_drv(OE) intel_qat(OE) authenc uio ib_isert iscsi_target_mod ib_srpt target_core_mod ib_srp scsi_transport_srp scsi_tgt ib_ucm rpcrdma sunrpc rdma_ucm ib_umad ib_uverbs ib_iser rdma_cm ib_ipoib iw_cm libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ib_cm mlx5_ib ib_core intelcas(OE) inteldisk(OE) iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support dell_smbios sparse_keymap dcdbas skx_edac intel_powerclamp coretemp intel_rapl iosf_mbi kvm irqbypass crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd sg joydev pcspkr ipmi_si i2c_i801 lpc_ich shpchp ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler mei_me acpi_power_meter
[  177.168071]  mei acpi_pad wmi nfit libnvdimm dm_multipath binfmt_misc ip_tables xfs libcrc32c mgag200 drm_kms_helper crc32c_intel syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mlx5_core fb_sys_fops ttm ixgbe drm igb mlxfw devlink mdio ptp i2c_algo_bit pps_core i2c_core dca sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common ahci libahci libata mpt2sas raid_class scsi_transport_sas megaraid_sas dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
[  177.168263] CPU: 24 PID: 5412 Comm: hdz-consumer Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE  ------------   3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1
[  177.168297] Hardware name: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R740/08D89F, BIOS 2.10.2 02/24/2021
[  177.168320] task: ffff93db22af3f40 ti: ffff93dc89354000 task.ti: ffff93dc89354000
[  177.168344] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff9e0caa47>]  [<ffffffff9e0caa47>] wake_q_add+0x17/0x50
[  177.168372] RSP: 0018:ffff93dc89357e48  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  177.168389] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffbe2ce6533018 RCX: 0000000000000fb0
[  177.168410] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff93dc89357e58
[  177.168432] RBP: ffff93dc89357e48 R08: ffffbe2ce6533000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  177.168453] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffbe2ce6533014
[  177.168475] R13: ffff93dc89357e58 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[  177.168497] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff93dca9400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  177.168540] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  177.168560] CR2: 0000000000000fb0 CR3: 00000002b7a0e000 CR4: 00000000007607e0
[  177.168583] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  177.168606] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  177.168629] PKRU: 00000000
[  177.168640] Call Trace:
[  177.168656]  [<ffffffff9e711b2e>] __mutex_unlock_slowpath+0x5e/0x90
[  177.168679]  [<ffffffff9e710fab>] mutex_unlock+0x1b/0x20
[  177.168699]  [<ffffffffc0637064>] consumer+0x64/0x90 [kdemo]
[  177.168723]  [<ffffffffc0637000>] ? 0xffffffffc0636fff
[  177.168746]  [<ffffffff9e0bae31>] kthread+0xd1/0xe0
[  177.168765]  [<ffffffff9e0bad60>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
[  177.168788]  [<ffffffff9e71f61d>] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin+0x7/0x21
[  177.168811]  [<ffffffff9e0bad60>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
[  177.168831] Code: 09 00 00 31 c9 31 d2 e8 18 41 ff ff eb e4 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 8d 8e b0 0f 00 00 31 c0 ba 01 00 00 00 48 89 e5 <f0> 48 0f b1 96 b0 0f 00 00 48 85 c0 74 0b 5d c3 66 0f 1f 84 00
[  177.168996] RIP  [<ffffffff9e0caa47>] wake_q_add+0x17/0x50
[  177.169017]  RSP <ffff93dc89357e48>
[  177.169959] CR2: 0000000000000fb0
```

producer stask

```
crash> bt 5411
PID: 5411   TASK: ffff93db22af4f10  CPU: 1   COMMAND: "hdz-producer"
bt: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffffffffffff  type: "cpu_online_map"
 #0 [ffff93dca8e48e48] crash_nmi_callback at ffffffff9e0533b7
 #1 [ffff93dca8e48e58] nmi_handle at ffffffff9e71790c
 #2 [ffff93dca8e48eb0] do_nmi at ffffffff9e717b2d
 #3 [ffff93dca8e48ef0] end_repeat_nmi at ffffffff9e716d79
 #4 [ffff93dca8e48f28] __vmalloc_node_range at ffffffff9e1d7518
    [exception RIP: mutex_unlock+20]
    RIP: ffffffff9e710fa4  RSP: ffff93ddafd73e98  RFLAGS: 00000202
    RAX: 0000000000000010  RBX: 0000000000000010  RCX: 0000000000000202
    RDX: ffff93ddafd73e98  RSI: 0000000000000018  RDI: 0000000000000001
    RBP: ffffffff9e710fa4   R8: ffffffff9e710fa4   R9: 0000000000000018
    R10: ffff93ddafd73e98  R11: 0000000000000202  R12: ffffffffffffffff
    R13: ffffbe2ce6535010  R14: ffffffffc0639240  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffc0639240  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
--- <(unknown) exception stack> ---
 #5 [ffff93ddafd73e98] mutex_unlock at ffffffff9e710fa4
 #6 [ffff93ddafd73ea0] producer at ffffffffc0637145 [kdemo]
 #7 [ffff93ddafd73ec8] kthread at ffffffff9e0bae31
 #8 [ffff93ddafd73f50] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin at ffffffff9e71f61d
```

Comment: To the question post you have added the call stack, but forgot to add the **error message** itself. According to the image, the error message is "unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference". Such error could caused by many reasons, and the code you have added to the post is definitely not sufficient for finding the reason.

Comment: I've simplified the code and updated the full code

Comment: Please, add the error message too (in textual form, not as *image*).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted the error log in textual form